# Change Google login account in Google foobar question task

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

I have linked my company Google suite email account with the Google foobar question task. Now I will be leaving the company in a few days after which they will deactivate my account.

How can I change my Google suite office Gmail account to my personal Google mail account to keep accessing the Google foobar tasks?